# Put the selected checkbox into a textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to put the selected checkbox into a textbox using jquery in order of the selected by the user? Everytime I select a random checkbox, the value of the textbox are depends on the pattern of the checkbox list. Here's my code:

```
<label>Favorite activities and areas: (Please check the box in order of priorities)</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="chckbox" value="C"/>C
<input type="checkbox" class="chckbox" value="C#"/>C#
<input type="checkbox" class="chckbox" value="PHP"/>PHP
<input type="checkbox" class="chckbox" value="Javascript"/>Javascript
<input type="checkbox" class="chckbox" value="Java"/>Java
<hr>
<input type="text" id="subject_areas" placeholder="Selected Checkboxes" disabled>
```

and here's my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.chckbox').click(function(){
   var text = "";
   $('.chckbox:checked').each(function(){
    text += $(this).val() + ', ';
   });
   text = text.substring(0,text.length-2);
   $('#subject_areas').val(text);
   });
 });
</script>
```

For example I select PHP and then I select C then the value of the textbox are "C, PHP" and that is wrong. The I want value are "PHP, C". Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to have an array variable set which you add to, or remove from depending on the `checked` property

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Set your array variable
    var checkboxValues = [];

    $('.chckbox').change(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            val = $this.val();
        //Check if checkbox is checked
        if($this.prop('checked')){
            //Add value to array
            checkboxValues.push(val);
        }else{
            //Get index of current value
            var index = checkboxValues.indexOf(val);

            //Remove value from array
            checkboxValues.splice(index,1);
        }

        //Use join() for a "cleaner" approach (no trimming required)
        $('#subject_areas').val(checkboxValues.join(', '));

    });
});
```